# Which is the identity element of $S_3 \times S_3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Which is the identity element of $S_3 \times S_3$ (that has 36 elements)? (Please do not confuse with $S_3$ that has 6 elements.)

Comment: $(e_G,e_H)\in G\times H$ is the identity in any direct product of groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ${}{}(1_{S_3}, 1_{S_3})$.

Comment: uh, why the downvote on this answer... ?

Comment: This answer is a special case of the more complete comment of Adam Hughes, which appeared earlier by 6 minutes (or so it seems).

Comment: @coffeemath You should instead be downvoting the person who left a comment instead of an answer, if that were possible.

Comment: @coffeemath That doesn't mean it's worth a downvote. Just not be worth an upvote. I should think a downvote should be reserved for answers that are incorrect, or poorly formatted, or in some other way harmful.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I completely agree. Not worth a downvote. I did not make the downvote, by the way. And +1

Comment: @MattS Note I didn't make the downvote, and my comment was meant as a possible explanation of why someone else did.

Comment: @coffeemath Understood. No offense intended even if you had downvoted, sorry if any was taken.